# One-dimensional convolution using Data.Vector

Tags: optimization, haskell, signal-processing

As part of some code I've written, I needed to perform a 1-D convolution. This convolution ends up happening quite often, so I wanted to optimise it (in some way other than using a FFT, though I could do this if necessary). I expect that my convolution kernels will be ~100, and the vector they are convolved with ~5k.

```
module Convolve (convolve) where

import qualified Data.Vector as V

convolve :: Num a => V.Vector a -> V.Vector a -> V.Vector a
convolve xs hs = V.map (V.sum . (V.zipWith (*) (V.reverse hs))) slices
    where
      slices = mkSlices (V.length hs) xs

mkSlices :: Num a => Int -> V.Vector a -> V.Vector (V.Vector a)
mkSlices size vec =
    V.map (paddedSlice size vec)
         (V.iterateN vecLength (+1) (-(size-1)))
    where vecLength = ((V.length vec)) - (-1 * (size -1)) 

paddedSlice size vec start 
    | size == 0 = V.empty
    | start < 0 && (size+start>0) =
        (V.replicate (abs start) 0) V.++ (paddedSlice (size+start) vec 0)
    | start < 0 && (size+start<=0) = V.replicate size 0
    | start > vL = V.replicate size 0
    | (start+size) > vL =
        (V.slice start (vL-start) vec)
        V.++ (V.replicate (start+size-vL) 0)
    | otherwise = V.slice start size vec 
    where vL = V.length vec
```

I don't (yet) have any experience optimising Haskell, and so I don't really know where to start. I asked in #haskell, which led to a few changes, but these did not have a drastic effect.

I was thinking to try Unboxed Vectors, but I don't think that `U.Vector` (`U.Vector a`) is possible. (If I'm wrong, it would be good to know!)

I was also thinking that parallelising might be a good idea. In general, is it better to parallelise "inwards" (e.g. call the outermost map as parallel) or "outwards"?